# What is the best and most performant way to group ratings data per dates in Ruby on rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a tasks table, for each completed task, the user can rate the task (from 1 to 5).

This is how the tasks table looks like:

```
tasks
  id: integer
  closed_at: datetime
  rating: integer
```

I then need to build an API response to get ratings per date in such format:

```
{ 
  "2023-02-23": [ 
    { rating: 1, count: 1 },
    { rating: 2, count: 5 },
    { rating: 3, count: 2 },
    { rating: 4, count: 30 },
    { rating: 5, count: 15}
  ], 
  "2023-02-24": [
    { rating: 1, count: 2 },
    ...
  ]
}
```

It's just an example, what I want is to get all ratings count per date.
In the above example, I have 1 task completed at 2023-02-23 and rated 1, 5 tasks completed the same day and rated 2...

What would be the best way to do that in ruby?
I was trying to find an SQL solution to that, but... I don't even know if this is possible.

Otherwise, I'd gladly take the most performant way using only ruby code after getting all the tasks.

I already have this working solution:

```rb
grouped_tasks_per_date = Task.all.group_by { |t| t.closed_at.to_date.to_s }

data = {}

grouped_tasks_per_date.each do |date, tasks|
  tasks_per_rating = tasks.group_by{|t| t.rating}

  data[date] = tasks_per_rating.map {|k, v| [k, v.length] }.to_h
end

data
=> {"2020-12-01"=>{1=>1, 2=>5, 3=>2, 4=>30, 5=>15}}
```

The above format I get is totally fine, but I'm using way too many loops to my taste... So... if you have any idea to improve my code or any other way to do that, please, share your ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using, please?

Comment: I'm using a MySQL Database :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're ever doing `Model.all` either you know the table will always be very small, or there's a better way.

Do the [grouping](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp), counting, and ordering in SQL...

```
select date_trunc('day', closed_at), rating, count(*)
from foo
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2
```

1 and 2 refer to the first and second selected columns: `date_trunc('day', closed_at)` and `rating`.

Exactly how you convert `closed_at` to a day depends on the SQL database you're using. [`date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) for Postgres, [`day`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) for MySQL.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/UJY9mQqc).

The equivalent Rails would use [`group`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group), `order`, and [`count`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count).

```
grouped = Task
  .select("datetrunc('day', closed_at)", rating)
  .group(1, 2)
  .order(1, 2)
  .count
```

And you can limit it to certain days with `where` like normal.

This will give you a Hash of Arrays like:

`{["2023-02-23", 1] => 1, ["2023-02-23", 2] => 5, ...}`

Comment: And if you're lazy and don't want to find the correct database functions there is always the [group_date](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) gem.

Comment: Thanks Schwern, I'll try your solution, and it looks like what I needed :-)
In the code, I don't really do a Model.all, but a "association.tasks" - and getting tasks closed at between two dates (last 3 months by default). So I'm not getting so many tasks.